# Construct a string/list based on two list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have 2 tables with the following data

Parent Table

```
S.No    Name     Fields
111    Parent1   title,fname,mname,lname,addr1,city,state,zip,county
112    Parent2    Address1,lname,firstName,suffix,countrycode,gender,zip,state,city,address2,email,phone
```

Child Table

```
S.No   mappingField   FieldIndex    ParentId
1      FirstName       1            111
2      LastName        3            111
3      AddressLine1    4            111
4      Country         8            111
5      LastName        1            112
6      FirstName       2            112
7      zip             6            112
8      state           7            112
9      workemail       10           112
10     workPhone       11           112
```

Now I need to create a string with the FieldIndex(Child Table) based on Field(Parent table)
in the following format.

I am expecting the output string in the order  of Fields column(Parent) where if there is any mapping field(in Child) available then it 
should show in and all other values should be replaced with a "$" sign..

```
ParentId 111 -- (9 fields)
$|FirstName|$|LastName|AddressLine1|$|$|$|Country

ParentId 112 --(12 fields)
$|LastName|FirstName|$|$|$|zip|state|$|$|workemail|workPhone
```

Here is my code:

```
 private string mapping(ChildData, ParentData)
    {
        string[] fieldList = ChildData.Fields;

        var IndInfoList = new List<string>();

        string[] headerList = ParentData.Fields.Split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < headerList.Length; i++)
        {           
            bool alreadyAdded = false;
            foreach (MyFields fields in fieldList)
            {
                if (i == ChildData.FieldIndex)
                {
                    IndInfoList.Add(ChildData.mappingField);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!alreadyAdded)
                    {
                        IndInfoList.Add("$");
                        alreadyAdded = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        string dataMapString = string.Join("|", IndInfoList);
        return dataMapString;
    }
```

Comment: Consider editing your post to ask a specific question. From reading, and re-reading, your post it is unclear to me what output you have and the output you expect.

Comment: I am expecting the output string in the order  of Parent table Fields where if there is any mapping field(in Child) available then it 
should show in and all other values should be replaced with a "$" sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ could simplify a lot of this for you e.g.

```
var items = new List<string>(parentList.Count);
foreach (var p in parentList)
{
    var fields = p.Fields.Split(',');
    var childData = childList.Where(x => x.ParentId == p.Id).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= fields.Length-1; i++)
    {
        var mappingField = childData.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FieldIndex == i).Select(x => x.mappingField);
        fields[i] = mappingField ?? "$";
    }
    items.Add(String.Join("|", fields));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the info.It looks like your code is looking for all the ParentIds in the parent table. I need only one parent id at a time, suppose I need Field column for parent id 111 only. can you give me code for that

Comment: @Henry this code iterates *all* the parents and maps all the related child fields to each one. So in effect, you should end up with the output you said you wanted?

Comment: I dont want all the Parents , I just want only the one parent. For Parent 111, I want the output in the format  "$|FirstName|$|LastName|AddressLine1|$|$|$|Country"